# Use xlswriter to name a file as current date and time

Tags: python, datetime, xlsxwriter

I am trying to use xlsxwriter to create an excel file and name a file as the current date and time. For context, I want to add this into a web scraper, which is set to run at midday everyday and export it to Excel. I want the file names to correspond with the scrape time.

I have tried using the datetime function with no success:

```
import xlsxwriter
import datetime

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.

todays_date = "'" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + '.xlsx' + "'"
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(todays_date)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

workbook.close()
```

Does anyone know why this is not working or another alternative?

@Sandeep Hukku - edited code below:

```
import xlsxwriter
import datetime

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.

# todays_date = "'" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + '.xlsx' + "'"
todays_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") )+ '.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(todays_date)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

workbook.close()
```

@Snehal Parmar - second update:

import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import xlsxwriter

```
# Web scraping
def make_soup(url):
    the_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup_data = BeautifulSoup(the_page, "html.parser")
    return soup_data


soup = make_soup('http://www.url.co.uk')


def getNames():
    for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
        for data in record.findAll('td'):
            for td_in_data in data.findAll('td', {"class": "propname"}):
                print(td_in_data.text)


def getRooms():
    for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
        for data in record.findAll('td'):
            for td_in_data in data.findAll('span', {"class": "beds"}):
                print(td_in_data.text)


def getRents():
    for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
        for data in record.findAll('td'):
            for td_in_data in data.findAll('td', {"class": "rentprice"}):
                print(td_in_data.text)


''' To do: get the scraped data to an Excel doc.'''

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.


todays_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") )+ '.xlsx'
todays_date = todays_date.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(todays_date)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Data to Excel.
Excel_dump = (
    ['Name', getNames()],
    ['Rent',   getRents()],
    ['Rooms',  getRooms()]
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0


# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in Excel_dump:
    worksheet.write()
    worksheet.write(col, row,     item)
    worksheet.write(col, row + 1)
    row += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but if you close the file after naming it and then again open in append mode and then add data into the file that might do the job. Sometimes create file is lazy operation, so what happens here is until nothing is written into the file its not create file and also operating system play important role too. Please and let me know, as its web scraper code I can't simulate here on my machine.

Got the issue: 
the problem is with the time part in the name of file, 
add the following :

```
todays_date = todays_date.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")
```

or

```
todays_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M") )+ '.xlsx'
```

I hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Snehal Parmar - not sure if that is possible with xlsxwriter?

Comment: try it please, it happened with me once when i was dumping some data. As your doing an network call in between the creating file and writing file, its very much possible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, at the moment I am not sure how to add this into my code above?!

Comment: Please check the edits I made to my answer, it will surely work.

Comment: If I post the full code with the scraper would you mind looking at it? Would be good to get your thought on it!

Comment: If recent edit don't works then do post the code. I will look into it.

Comment: The most recent edit worked on its own. Just now that I have added to my scraper it is not. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133576/discussion-between-snehal-parmar-and-maverick).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write
`todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + '.xlsx'` instead of
`todays_date = "'" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + '.xlsx' + "'"`

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep Hukku - unfortunately that does not work, I had tried that already. In both instances I am finding that it creates a text file named as the current date/time.

Comment: Strange... Just tested it again and it creates a text file with no data and not an Excel file.

Comment: can you just for once try `todays_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") )+ '.xlsx'`. This might fix your problem. Do inform if this does help you.

Comment: Tried again, still creating as text file and not Excel. Added the updated code below